# Oracle: Move column to new table, eliminate non-unique rows remaining in original table while maintaining foreign relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the following:

Table 1: Person_Favorite_Food

```
id name   address          favorite_food
------------------------------------------
1  Dave   123 Cherry Ln    Pizza
2  Dave   123 Cherry Ln    Cheeseburger
3  Dave   456 Peachtree St Ice cream
4  Cindy  789 Grove Rd     Pizza
```

id - primary key

unique key constraint on the following columns: name, address and food

Since each person can have more than one favorite food item I'd like to split Table 1 into two tables like the following:

Table 2: Person

```
id name   address          
--------------------------
1  Dave   123 Cherry Ln    
3  Dave   456 Peachtree St 
4  Cindy  789 Grove Rd
```

Table 3: Person_Favorite_Food

```
person_id  favorite_food
-----------------
1          Pizza
1          Cheeseburger
3          Ice cream
4          Pizza
```

How would I go about doing this in Oracle?

*Note: In the original table Rows 1 and 2 represent favorite food for the same person so the favorite food entries in the Person_Favorite_Food table will need to have the same identifier for both of those entries although the identifiers are different in the initial table.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
create table new1 as
    select distinct id, name, address
    from t;

create table new2 as
    select id, favorite_food
    from t;
```

I would recommend create *two* new tables and not trying to morph the existing table into one of the new ones.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not quite what I need. I've updated the original post with more information. Also, I was hoping that I'd be able to create only one table and update the other if possible.

Comment: @cscdevcm12 . . . It is not worth it.  Create two new tables with the data you want.

Comment: Maybe not. That distinct on new1 would new to be just on name and address to  accomplish my goal. Any idea how to solve the issue of making sure identifiers from rows eliminated in new1 due to distinct are not used in new2. Those will need to have the same identifier as the one corresponding row (name, address) left in new1.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple aggregation to create table person:

```
create table person as 
select min(id) id, name, address 
  from person_favorite_food
  group by name, address;
```

Use the same query in `merge` to change id for some rows:

```
merge into person_favorite_food a
using (select min(id) id, name, address from person_favorite_food group by name, address) b
on (a.name = b.name and a.address = b.address)
when matched then update set a.id = b.id;
```

Drop unwanted columns:

```
alter table person_favorite_food drop (name, address);
```

Done. Demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebb1aefb1460e7ef0b87db0f2635e7c9).